# SerialDataReceivedEventHandler not being fired

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have been trying to establish a serial port communication in C#. I see, that the event handler for reading data doesnt get fired. The initial strings are the format in which i need to send the data to a register( for eg 0000 reg gets the value of 1180).

Please let me know if i am missing something here.
PS: Just a beginner.

```
class Program
    {
        static SerialPort _serialPort;

        public static void Main()
        {


            string phyad = "17";
            string regad = "0000";
            string value = "1180";

            string readad = phyad + regad + "=" + "/";

            string combo = phyad + regad + value + "=" + "/";

            _serialPort = new SerialPort();


            _serialPort.PortName = "COM4";
            _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            _serialPort.Open();
            _serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;



            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(combo);
            _serialPort.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(MyDataReceivedHandler);


        }

        private static void MyDataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_serialPort.ReadExisting());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `MyDataReceivedHandler` meant to be a function? It doesn't appear that you're sending any parameters to it....Or calling it as a function

Comment: how did you test, that the data from the device really arrives at the port? did you try to read the port manually? or use a terminal programm, like "HTerm" ?

Comment: Add the event handler before you write to the port - if the device responds immediately upon Write you might miss the response.

Comment: Adding the event handler before helped me get the value. However, if there is a register which gives out different values(frame count), and if i want to display in the console while its updating, how do we approach that scenario?